# Can't find specific backup in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a DB in google cloud SQL. I enabled every day backup.
I needed to restore today a backup, but the last DB backup that was available is 5 days ago. I read that google cloud only backs up the deltas.
I know for sure that data was changed for the past 5 days ago, I also see the backup file of yesterday in the storage bucket.

Am I missing something some setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was most likely caused by a known issue affecting a small subset of Cloud SQL instances starting from May 4th. The issue was fully fixed by May 12th. Manually triggered backup operations were not affected.

You can expect to see daily backup at all times with automated backups enabled. You are correct that backups for Second Generation instances are [incremental](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups#about_backup_size), but that doesn't affect automated schedule.

Comment: Thank you very much. Does it mean I can rely on the backup now? Where can I read more about this issue?

Comment: Yes, Cloud SQL Second Generation backups should be back to normal for everyone now.Two main resources would be checking [Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/) or reaching out to Support team if you purchased support package. Depending on severity of the issue it might show up on the Status Dashboard only over the course of it.